# Как возвращать клиенту страницу не из заданного файла?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при запросе `http://site/dir/любой_текст` возвращалась страница `http://site/server/file.php`, обработанная PHP, и чтобы PHP знал, что обращаются к странице `любой_текст`.

Comment: RewriteRule напишите и будет вам счастье

Comment: @ArchDemon, ну а как? Напишите в ответах.